# Hide/Show constrained Window

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

We are trying to prevent unnecessary rendering and therefor just want to hide and show a window containing a quite huge grid.

The window itself is constrained to the viewport by calling

```
App.Instance.getViewPort().add(scope.myWindowRef = Ext.create('Ext.Window'),{ 
    constrainHeader: true 
    /* and the rest of the cfg */ 
});
scope.myWindowRef.on('close',function(win){ win.hide(); win.caller.enable(); return false; });
```

We have a button listeners inside the controller which should now `show` an `hide` window

```
onOpenWin: function(button) {
    button.disable();
    var scope = this,
        win = scope.myWindowRef;
    win.caller = button;
    win.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [beforeclose](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-event-beforeclose) event when you want to stop the destruction of the window. The close event is already to late!

Answer (score 1):

check out [closeAction](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closeAction) config - `closeAction:'hide'` should do..

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I would have marked your answer as correct, but I need to reenable the button and for that case sra has the better answer. Anyway you got my +1